# What is the difference of roc_auc values in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn for my binary classification dataset using 10-fold cross validation as follows. I use "accuracy", "precision_weighted", "recall_weighted", "f1_weighted" to measure my results.

```
scores = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=k_fold, scoring=("accuracy", "precision_weighted", "recall_weighted", "f1_weighted"))
print(scores)
```

I want to get the roc_auc results as well. When I check sklearn they provide the following options.

```
‘roc_auc’
‘roc_auc_ovr’
‘roc_auc_ovo’
‘roc_auc_ovr_weighted’
‘roc_auc_ovo_weighted’
```

Since, I am using `weighted` measures for the precision, recall and f-measure, I am thinking that I should use either `roc_auc_ovr_weighted`, `roc_auc_ovo_weighted`. However, I am not clear what is the difference between them. Please suggest me a suitable one that suits binary classification problems.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) `roc_auc` is the only one suitable for binary classification. The `weighted`, `ovr` and `ovo` are use for multi-class problems.

Answer (score 1):

you should use 'balanced_accuracy' as well to be consistent with "precision_weighted", "recall_weighted" and "f1_weighted"